# Does stumbling around in the dark hurt me?

Tags: might-and-magic-x-legacy

I usually don't bother casting spells like Darkvision or Torchlight when running around at night because they seem like a waste of mana. I can still see well enough in the darkness to navigate.

Does darkness matter for anything beyond the ability to navigate an area, though? Does it affect anything like hit or evade chance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a fan of the Series M&M Part 6+ i can hardly recall having any gameplay advantages using Lightsource Spells.
Except the different vision all do the same : Brighten your enviroment.

Here is a forum post from the off. forums from ubisoft:

> BTW, the game does not penalize you in any way for using a light spell of some kind--you are not "less visible" to your enemies...;) They will attack and fight the same whether you have a light spell going or you don't. Likewise, your attacks against your enemies are not degraded if you cannot see them, either. This condition basically means that you and your enemies have the same advantages in terms of dark-vision; neither has an advantage.

Source : [Ubisoft Forum Post](http://forums.ubi.com/showthread.php/879985-The-point-of-torchlight-spell?s=e623d32976a9eb769d38fcf52195e648&p=9973161&viewfull=1#post9973161)

Comment: So... then the answer is that there isn't any consequences for not using a light or darkvision spell? Summarize the answer at the top and then provide the compelling evidence below it.

Comment: Torch enlightens your environment  and Darkvision lets you see in the dark. No Gameplay benefits if you using a brigth setup and definitly useful for a more moody low brigthness.

Comment: I realize you're pretty new around here. Can you interpret the evidence and state the answer in one or two sentences at the top of your post? Right now, I have to read the entire paragraph of your source in order to try to interpret what the answer is myself. It'd be helpful if you could state "No, it doesn't hurt" or something clear to that effect and then provide the compelling evidence after it.